# Meteorjs using $near on Client Side

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I try to get the cursor of a collection on client side.

Following Code is given:

**Server**

```
// make sure that $near stuff works
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Business._ensureIndex({'data.located':'2dsphere'});
});
// publish my collection
Meteor.publish('business', function(sq){
return Business.find(sq);
});
```

**Client & Server**

```
 Business = new Meteor.Collection('business');
```

**Client**

```
var searchQuery = {};
searchQuery['data.located'] = {
    $near : {
        $geometry : {
            type : 'Point',
            coordinates : [50, 50]
        },
        $maxDistance : 50000
    }
};
Meteor.subscribe('business', searchQuery);
Business.find(searchQuery);
```

The problem is, that the cursors has 0 results. When I use this search on Server side i got the right count of results! The Collection.find() method is called when my template is rendered.

First i thougth that its asynchron because of this i tried to get the result in a timeout callback but this does not solve the problem.

Is it possible that the $near searchfunction cant be use on client-side ? If its not possible how is it possible to solve this ?

Comment: Not likely. That would seem a little out of minimongo's depth. Whilst there is a fair bit of convenience in the meteor API, you are actually a lot better of implementing this server side and then accessing the custom method as published in order to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)  sorting with `$near` was implemented in minimongo in meteor v0.7.1.1.

It looks like you are doing the `find` immediately after the `subscribe`. If that's the case, the data won't be transmitted to the client before the `find` executes. Assuming your query is correct, if you just wait for the data to be ready it may work. Try something like this:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('business', searchQuery, function() {
  console.log(Business.findOne(searchQuery));
});
```

Note that your code shows subscribing without the required name (`'business'`) - I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: You're right - I subscribe without the correct name but its only a typo. I just triet my case with a window.timeout before - but i will check your solution and comment soon.

Comment: Thats it. Thats all. I thougth that i do not need the callback because of the fact that there is an autoupdate in it when i use the find() method. Maybe a stupid mind ... dunno ...but works great. Thanks :)

Comment: I am sorry. My comment was wrong. With your fix it also does not work! :(